# Struggling with returning a Task using MongoDriver and catching the error

Tags: c#, mongodb, blazor

Trying to get all the elements in the Books Mongo collection and then returning the error if there is an Error. I also want to await the method thus I included a Task. The problem is exceptionTask is of type Task. How do I chane this method so I can return the exception and display this error on the client side.

Using Blazor, C# and Mongo Driver.

The `_books.Find(book => true).ToList()` is working fine.

The method:

```
public async Task<List<Book>> GetAll()
    {
          List<Book> list;
          try
          {
               list = await Task.Run(() => _books.Find(book => true).ToList()); ;
               return list;
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
          var exceptionTask = new Task(() => { throw e; });
          exceptionTask.RunSynchronously();
          return exceptionTask;
          }
    
    }
```

The error says at `return excpetionTask`: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.Data.Book>

Thank you for your help.

Comment: _"Stuggling with"_ isn't descriptive of the problem you're facing. Please update your title following the guidelines in [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo natively supports async/await, you don't need to wrap it in a `Task`:

```
list = await _books.Find(book => true).ToListAsync();
```

Or, simply return its result:

```
return await _books.Find(book => true).ToListAsync();
```

Moving onto your `catch (Exception e)`, you seem to be doing little more than wrapping the exception in its own `Task`, but for no benefit as you're effectively catching and immediately rethrowing the exception. As such, I'd simply rewrite the method like this and let the exception bubble up by itself:

```cs
public async Task<List<Book>> GetAll()
{
    return await _books.Find(book => true).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: So if I write the method as you suggested and there is an error fetching all the books then the Error message will be catched when I call the GetAll() method?

Comment: @franco no, it won't - it will just bubble up. But you were effectively catching and rethrowing it anyway, meaning that the caller would still have to handle an exception even in your code.

Comment: Thank you. How do I catch the error then?

Comment: @franco you weren't doing anything to handle the error in your code, you were effectively rethrowing it. Why do you want to catch it?

Comment: To inform the user something went wrong with the DB query. Or is there a better way of dealing with it? Cause u have to inform the user if something went wrong and typically with the type of error so they can inform the admins if this was a real life web app.

Comment: Catching an error doesn't inform the error without additional code though. Your code above did nothing other than let the error bubble up to the calling method, which is little different to not catching it and letting it bubble up naturally. In case it's unclear: the error will bubble up even if you don't catch and rethrow it. If you want to add logging then a simple try/catch the same as in any sync code will work just fine.